# can i remove a:after with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I got breadcrumbs and its build up like this. `<div> <p> <a>` so i style the a and a:after in the css

i want to remove the `:after` on the last a, is that possible somehow?

I got this code and i can addClass to the last element but no really remove the `:after`

```
$('#breadcrumbs p > a:last').removeClass('a:after');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:after` is a selector and cannot be removed. You could create a css class to remove any styling that's been added to the `a:after` css rule though.

```
$('#breadcrumbs p > a:last').addClass('reset_link_style_class');
```

Comment: yea i did that, i notice now that it works for some pages in my application, strange problem. thats another issue thoght, thanks

Comment: Typicall was a script on those sites that was broken so made this not work.